# Построение ассоциации

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подскажите как построить связь между моделями следующим образом:
- Пользователь может иметь много постов
- Разные пользователи могут писать друг-другу посты на стену(как в соц.сетях, а именно когда ты можешь сам создать запись или у тебя на странице ее может создать другой пользователь.

Answer (score 2):

Модель пользователя:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_one  :wall
end
```

Модель постов:

```
# models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :posts
  belongs_to :wall
end
```

Модель стены/блога и т.п :

```
# models/wall.rb
class Wall < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :posts
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Таким образом, вы можете создавать записи, у которых будет автор и которые будут привязаны к конкретной стене. Запрос для записей стены будет выглядеть так:

```
@posts = Wall.find(wall_id).posts
```

Запрос для записей конкретного юзера:

```
@user_posts = Wall.find(wall_id).posts.where(user: @user)
```

Чтобы получить стену конкретного юзера:

```
@wall = @user.wall
```

Чтобы получить записи со стены конкретного юзера:

```
@posts = @user.wall.posts
```

Чтобы получить записи владельца стены:

```
@owner_posts = @user.wall.posts.where(user: @user)
```